# wxWidgets - Add items to sizer via DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, dll, wxwidgets

I have a GUI set up with wxWidgets (C++, MSVC) and part of the functionality is to add elements to the GUI via DLL's. Essentially, I would be passing in a sizer to the DLL which will in turn add the elements based on what is in the DLL.

Could someone just point me in the right direction on how to get the DLL set up? I have looked, but don't see anything that's similar to what I'm looking for. The programming of the elements is fine with me, I just need to understand how to structure the DLL programming.

Help appreciated.

---

UPDATE

I've done something similar to http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Programs_That_Support_Plugins.

Essentially, I get Access violation reading location errors whenever I try using wxWidgets components from within the DLL.

In the samplePlugin.cpp, If I use

```
void samplePlugin::PerformTasks()
{
   wxMessageBox(_("I would if I could..."));
}
```

I get the error. If, however, I use

```
void samplePlugin::PerformTasks()
{
   MessageBox(0,"Testing this thing","Test",0);
}
```

which is not wxWidgets, but rather native to the OS, the message box works fine.

I've tried adding WXUSINGDLL;WXMAKINGDLL; in the Preprocessor Definitions in MSVC in both the DLL and the App projects. The DLL compiles fine, but I can't even compile the App in that case and get exceptions.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: "add the elements based on what is in the DLL." So, what IS in the DLL?  Please give an example of something 'in the DLL' and the element  that is added.

Comment: Say I have code in the DLL of a label, radiobutton, etc. I would like to add those widgets to the sizer that I'm passing in from the main GUI application.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense because adding sizer elements from a DLL is not different at all from adding them from the main application. Your question seems to be more about "How do I write a DLL" but then it's too general.

Comment: Well, VZ, I think that questions is normal for wxWidgets development. There are several topics regarding this at official forums but they don't help much. There are differences between non-GUI DLLs without wxWidgets and DLLs which use wxWidgets. E.g. you need to use Multi-Threaded Debug DLL/Multi-Threaded DLL compiler settings, otherwise it won't work. I personally had to spend much time digging forums and trying different compiler/linker settings and DLL structure (e.g. with and without application class in DLL) before I could implement such plugin. But now it looks trivial after all.

Comment: Hi, could you please take a look at my original post? I added an update to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a DLL project and specify the preprocessor directive e.g. /DIFLOOR_EXPORTS_COMMONPLUGINBASE (this preprocessor variable only in DLL project)

Then create a header which specifies whether your classes are imported or exported:

**CommonPluing.h**

```
#ifndef _COMMONPLUGIN_H
#define _COMMONPLUGIN_H

#if defined(__WXMSW__)
#ifdef IFLOOR_EXPORTS_COMMONPLUGINBASE
#define IFLOOR_API_COMMONPLUGINBASE __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define IFLOOR_API_COMMONPLUGINBASE __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define IFLOOR_API_COMMONPLUGINBASE
#endif

#endif // _COMMONPLUGIN_H
```

Then create your exported class and add the specifier from first header:

**CommonConfigWindowBase.h**

```
class IFLOOR_API_COMMONPLUGINBASE CommonConfigWindowBase : public wxPanel 
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS(CommonConfigWindowBase)
public:
    /// Constructors
    CommonConfigWindowBase();
    CommonConfigWindowBase(wxWindow *parent,
        wxWindowID winid = wxID_ANY,
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
        long style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL | wxNO_BORDER,
        const wxString& name = wxPanelNameStr);

    /// Pseudo ctor
    bool Create(wxWindow *parent,
        wxWindowID winid = wxID_ANY,
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
        long style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL | wxNO_BORDER,
        const wxString& name = wxPanelNameStr);

    virtual ~CommonConfigWindowBase();

    /// Reads config from the effect
    virtual bool ReadConfig(){return true;}

    /// Saves config to the effect
    virtual bool SaveConfig(){return true;}
};
```

Create the exported function callable from main executable (you may want to create a wrapper class and call methods which return wxWindow *).
You need an exported method for creating the plugin object and for deleting it. Also you need a !!! virtual destructors !!! for exported object and for your windows.
so assuming that SportEffectPlugin contains a wxWindow * CreateConfigWindow(wxWindow * parent) method:

**Exports.cpp**

```
#include "stdwx.h"
#include "CommonConfigWindowBase.h"

IFLOOR_API_COMMONPLUGINBASE IFloorEffectPluginBase * CreatePlugin(const wxString& sBasePath, iFloorBlobVector * blobs)
{
    return new SportEffectPlugin(sBasePath, blobs);
}

IFLOOR_API_COMMONPLUGINBASE void DeletePlugin(IFloorEffectPluginBase * plugin)
{
    wxDELETE(plugin);
}
```

Then in main app load the DLL (you will need to adopt the following code for your needs):

**Loader.cpp**

```
bool IFloorSystem::LoadPlugins(bool forceProgramPath)
{
    if (!m_DefaultPlugin)
    {
        m_DefaultPlugin = new DefaultEffectPlugin(GetDefaultGraphicsPath());
        RegisterEffectPlugin(m_DefaultPlugin);
    }

    wxFileName fn;
    fn.AssignDir(GetPluginsPath(forceProgramPath));
    wxLogDebug(wxT("%s"), fn.GetFullPath().data());
    fn.AppendDir(wxT("effects"));
    wxLogDebug(wxT("%s"), fn.GetFullPath().data());
    if (!fn.DirExists())
        return false;
    wxDir dir(fn.GetFullPath());
    if (!dir.IsOpened())
        return false;

    // scan for plugins
    wxString filename;
    wxString ext = wxT("*.dll"); // TODO: change ext for different platforms
    bool bFound = dir.GetFirst(&filename, ext, wxDIR_FILES);
    while (bFound)
    {
        fn.SetFullName(filename);
        wxDynamicLibrary * dll = new wxDynamicLibrary(fn.GetFullPath());
        if (dll->IsLoaded())
        {
            wxDYNLIB_FUNCTION(CreatePlugin_function, CreatePlugin, *dll);
            if (pfnCreatePlugin)
            {
                IFloorEffectPluginBase* plugin = pfnCreatePlugin(GetDefaultGraphicsPath(), &IFloorStorage::Instance().GetBlobs());
                RegisterEffectPlugin(plugin);
                m_DllList.Append(dll);
                m_MapPluginsDll[plugin] = dll;
            }
            else
                wxDELETE(dll);
        }
        bFound = dir.GetNext(&filename);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in the end you will need to unload plugins and delete all loaded objects by calling the function from DLL:

```
bool IFloorSystem::UnRegisterEffectPlugin(IFloorEffectPluginBase * plugin)
{
    IFloorEffectPluginBaseList::compatibility_iterator it = m_Plugins.Find(plugin);
    if (it == NULL)
        return false;

    do 
    {
        wxDynamicLibrary * dll = m_MapPluginsDll[plugin];
        if (!dll) // Probably plugin was not loaded from dll
            break;

        wxDYNLIB_FUNCTION(DeletePlugin_function, DeletePlugin, *dll);
        if (pfnDeletePlugin)
        {
            pfnDeletePlugin(plugin);
            m_Plugins.Erase(it);
            m_MapPluginsDll.erase(plugin);
            return true;
        }
    } while (false);

    // If plugin is not loaded from DLL
    wxDELETE(plugin);
    m_Plugins.Erase(it);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please take a look at my original post? I added an update to it. Thank you.

Comment: Here is what I have in CMake script (preprocessor definitions): set(PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS ${PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS};/D_USRDLL;/DIFLOOR_EXPORTS_COMMONPLUGINBASE;/D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS) - you can see that IFLOOR_EXPORTS_COMMONPLUGINBASE is used in CommonPlugin.h for defining IFLOOR_API_COMMONPLUGINBASE macro which holds export specifier for DLL classes. Also don't forget  that you need to build wxWidgets as DLL and use runtime libs as Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (for Debug) and Multi-Threaded DLL (for Release) and same options in  your DLL and host app.

Comment: Here is what I have in DLL's pre-processor definitions: WIN32;_WINDOWS;NDEBUG;WXUSINGDLL;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE;_UNICODE;__WXDEBUG__=1;_USRDLL;IFLOOR_EXPORTS_COMMONPLUGINBASE;CMAKE_INTDIR="Release";CommonPluginBase_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)

Comment: Pre-processor definitions of host app: WIN32;_WINDOWS;NDEBUG;WXUSINGDLL;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE;_UNICODE;__WXDEBUG__=1;_USRDLL;wxUSE_NO_MANIFEST=1;__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS;CMAKE_INTDIR="Release";%(PreprocessorDefinitions)

Comment: Thank you for the info, I've gotten it to work.

I do have another question, however. I have a wxNotebook and essentially I have different dll's loaded in each page. How would I go about navigating through the pages and then working with its specific dll at any point in time?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When frame is created you scan for plugins, load plugin objects, create pages from DLL. Each DLL contains its data internally and each tab knows which data to use. If you want to keep data in app, you may provide the pointer to model object to each plugin into the exported function which creates the notebook tab, then save the pointer in that created control and it will know which data model you connected to it.

Comment: That's sort of what I meant. In each DLL, I have specific functions. I may want to switch notebook tabs and come back to one to call a specific function for that particular DLL. How would I go about calling that specific plugin->function again? As far as I can tell, the plugin gets out of scope when I add it to the notebook tab. What I'm thinking of doing is creating a vector with the needed scope and adding the plugins to it so I can have access to them whenever I need. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using vector of plugins is a good enough solution. You will anyway need to delete them in the end and unregister DLLs (see my code). Also you can assign the plugin object to the tab by using SetClientData() I think and you will always know which tab corresponds to which plugin. If you need to change the selected tab in main window from plugin, you may pass your main window to plugin as wxEvtHandler * and pass events to it, then handle these events in main window.